# WPF Ellipse wont resize correctly on MouseEnter Event

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using ChartView Telerik WPF Library. I want the points to get bigger when the user hovers over them. But for some reason it is not working as expected. The Ellipse gets bigger but it does not resize correctly. But I don't understand why. The other properties as border color and thickness are working correctly. 
Can someone tell me what am I missing here ?

This is how it looks currently when I try to resize the point :
[image: ChartView Points Resize]

Here is the Source Code:

```
private FrameworkElementFactory AddPointsToSeries(KeyValuePair<ChartSerie, List<ChartDataPoint>> chartSeries, int colorPaletteIndex)
    {
        var seriesPredefinedColor = this.ChartBase.Palette.GlobalEntries[colorPaletteIndex].Fill;

        FrameworkElementFactory frameworkElement = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Ellipse));
        frameworkElement.SetValue(Ellipse.FillProperty, ColorService.BrushFromHex(chartSeries.Key.ColorHex) ?? seriesPredefinedColor);
        frameworkElement.SetValue(Ellipse.HeightProperty, 9.0D);
        frameworkElement.SetValue(Ellipse.WidthProperty, 9.0D);


        frameworkElement.AddHandler(Ellipse.MouseEnterEvent, new MouseEventHandler((sender, args) =>
           {
               Ellipse ellipse = (Ellipse)sender;
               ellipse.Stroke = ColorService.BrushFromHex(ColorService.BlendHex((chartSeries.Key.ColorHex ?? ColorService.BrushToHex(seriesPredefinedColor)), "#000000", 0.4));

               // this is not correctly applied!
               ellipse.Width = 15;
               ellipse.Height = 15;

               ellipse.StrokeThickness = 2;
           }));

        frameworkElement.AddHandler(Ellipse.MouseLeaveEvent, new MouseEventHandler((sender, args) =>
           {
               Ellipse ellipse = (Ellipse)sender;
               ellipse.Height = 8;
               ellipse.Width  = 8;

               ellipse.Stroke = null;
           }));


        return frameworkElement;
    }

    // Here I create the Line Series and here I use the AddPointsToSeries Method
    private LineSeries CreateLineSeries(KeyValuePair<ChartSerie, List<ChartDataPoint>> chartSeries, ChartLegendSettings legendSettings,
                                        int colorPaletteIndex)
    {
        FrameworkElementFactory addPoints = AddPointsToSeries(chartSeries, colorPaletteIndex);
        var lineSerie = new LineSeries()
        {
            VerticalAxis    = CreateMultipleVerticalAxis(chartSeries, colorPaletteIndex, out var multipleVerticalAxis) ? multipleVerticalAxis : null,
            ZIndex          = 150, // the line series should always be displayed on top of other series.
            StrokeThickness = 3.5,
            LegendSettings  = (SeriesLegendSettings)legendSettings,
            Opacity         = 0.8,
            StackGroupKey = chartSeries.Key.Group,
            CombineMode   = string.IsNullOrEmpty(chartSeries.Key.Group) ? ChartSeriesCombineMode.None : ChartSeriesCombineMode.Stack,

            PointTemplate = new DataTemplate()
            {
                VisualTree = addPoints,
            },
        };

        // this is the color of line series
        if (chartSeries.Key.ColorHex != null)
        {
            lineSerie.Stroke = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(chartSeries.Key.ColorHex));
        }

        foreach (ChartDataPoint serie in chartSeries.Value)
        {
            lineSerie.DataPoints.Add(new CategoricalDataPoint()
            {
                Category = serie.XPoint.Label,
                Value    = (double?)serie.Value,
            });
        }

        return lineSerie;
    }
```

Comment: Note that an Ellipse element isn't drawn centered, but top/left aligned. You might set a negative Margin (with its radius, e.g. half of its width/height), or use a Path element with an EllipseGeometry.

Comment: @Clemens I was also wondering why is the Ellipse not centered. Thanks for clarifying. I will try tomorrow to solve that problem too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was answered my Martin Ivanov:

> This behavior comes from the size caching mechanism of the chart. Basically, the control is setting the size of the visual when initially loaded and then it doesn't change it unless something on the chart's API changes. In order to achieve your requirement you can wrap the ellipse in a Grid panel and its Width and Height properties to be the same (or little bigger) then the size of the bigger ellipse.

This is the solution:

```
private FrameworkElementFactory AddPointsToSeries(KeyValuePair<ChartSerie, List<ChartDataPoint>> chartSeries, int colorPaletteIndex)
    {
        var   seriesPredefinedColor = this.ChartBase.Palette.GlobalEntries[colorPaletteIndex].Fill;
        Brush brush                 = chartSeries.Key.ColorHex == null ? (seriesPredefinedColor) : ColorService.HexToBrush(chartSeries.Key.ColorHex);
        Brush mouseOnEnterColor     = new SolidColorBrush(ColorService.ChangeColorLightness(ColorService.BrushToColor(brush), 0.8));

        double ellipseMouseOverStrokeThickness = 2;
        double ellipseMouseOverHeightWidth     = 13;
        double ellipseStrokeThickness          = 1;
        double ellipseHeightWidth              = 9;

        FrameworkElementFactory frameworkElement = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Ellipse));
        frameworkElement.SetValue(Ellipse.FillProperty, brush);
        frameworkElement.SetValue(Ellipse.MarginProperty, new Thickness(-4.5));
        frameworkElement.SetValue(Ellipse.HeightProperty, ellipseHeightWidth);
        frameworkElement.SetValue(Ellipse.WidthProperty, ellipseHeightWidth);
        frameworkElement.SetValue(Ellipse.StrokeProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White));
        frameworkElement.SetValue(Ellipse.StrokeThicknessProperty, ellipseStrokeThickness);


        frameworkElement.AddHandler(Ellipse.MouseEnterEvent, new MouseEventHandler((sender, args) =>
                                                                                   {
                                                                                       Ellipse ellipse = (Ellipse)sender;
                                                                                       ellipse.Fill            = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                                                                                       ellipse.Stroke          = mouseOnEnterColor;
                                                                                       ellipse.StrokeThickness = ellipseMouseOverStrokeThickness;
                                                                                       ellipse.Width           = ellipseMouseOverHeightWidth;
                                                                                       ellipse.Height          = ellipseMouseOverHeightWidth;
                                                                                   }));

        frameworkElement.AddHandler(Ellipse.MouseLeaveEvent, new MouseEventHandler((sender, args) =>
                                                                                   {
                                                                                       Ellipse ellipse = (Ellipse)sender;
                                                                                       ellipse.Stroke          = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                                                                                       ellipse.Fill            = brush;
                                                                                       ellipse.StrokeThickness = ellipseStrokeThickness;
                                                                                       ellipse.Height          = ellipseHeightWidth;
                                                                                       ellipse.Width           = ellipseHeightWidth;
                                                                                   }));

        FrameworkElementFactory stackPanelFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Grid));
        stackPanelFactory.SetValue(Grid.HeightProperty, ellipseMouseOverHeightWidth + ellipseMouseOverStrokeThickness);
        stackPanelFactory.SetValue(Grid.WidthProperty, ellipseMouseOverHeightWidth  + ellipseMouseOverStrokeThickness);
        stackPanelFactory.AppendChild(frameworkElement);

        return stackPanelFactory;
    }
```

Now it looks like this:

[image: chartview point animations]